# Embeded IFrame html page read IFrame html attributes

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Can an embedded HTML page read html attributes from the Iframe. 
One possible solution that comes to mind is reading the attributes at the page where the Iframe is inserted and setting them as URL params.

Any other easier and direct options out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the iframe and the parent page share the same domain, I think you can use Javascript to do something like `parent.document.getElementById('myIframeId').getAttribute("attrName")`. But if they are cross-domain, the way you mentioned is a way to go.